# How Powershell can get data after number of "/"

Tags: string, powershell, format

Can somebody help me with powershell select string please.

Example I have a link "https://abv.com/personal/John/Documents/01/Events/02/NO_SHOW.xlsx"

Is there anyway I get use powershell and get only data after 5 "/" like this:
"https://abv.com/personal/John/"

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be:

```
("https://abv.com/personal/John/Documents/01/Events/02/NO_SHOW.xlsx" -split '/')[0..4] -join '/'
```

or if you need the last `'/'` then:

```
(("https://abv.com/personal/John/Documents/01/Events/02/NO_SHOW.xlsx" -split '/')[0..4] -join '/') + '/'
```

If you need the other part of the string you may take this approach:

```
#contains all the details
$addressArray = "https://abv.com/personal/John/Documents/01/Events/02/NO_SHOW.xlsx" -split '/'

#contains only the first five
$firstFive = ($addressArray[0..4] -join '/') + '/'

#contains the rest of the symbols
$theRest = $addressArray[5..($addressArray.Count -1)] -join '/'
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Everyone started from somewhere, no one was born with skills encoded into the DNA. I would suggest to review get-help about_ ... quite a lot of useful topics! It is like book for powershell in powershell :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Split()`](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html) to split the URL on `'/'`, [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) to select the first `5` parts,  and [`Join-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/join-string?view=powershell-7) to join the parts back up with `'/'`:

```
PS C:\> $url = 'https://abv.com/personal/John/Documents/01/Events/02/NO_SHOW.xlsx'
PS C:\> $url.Split('/') | Select-Object -First 5 | Join-String -Separator '/'
https://abv.com/personal/John
```

If you want the rest of the data, use `-Last 5` to get the last five parts instead:

```
PS C:\> $url.Split('/') | Select-Object -Last 5 | Join-String -Separator '/'
Documents/01/Events/02/NO_SHOW.xlsx
```